# Should default Debian time zone: 'Etc/UTC be changed?

Tags: django, debian, utc

Should the default Debian time zone Etc/UTC be changed fo all practical purposes including administration or development using Django or other frameworks?

Comment: IMO it should not be changed. Everything inside your app should be in UTC time whereas each time you want to present something to the user, only then, use time-zone aware dates/times.

Comment: why use UTC as default?

Comment: Because you'll don't have to mess around with different timezones. Internally you handle datetimes in UTC (much easier to handle) and externally convert (or not) UTC to time-aware zone.